# execute trigger before any delete actually happens

Tags: postgresql

The problem is, my trigger (`ON DELETE`) is executed after parent records have been deleted and by the time the grandchild record gets its trigger executed I can't do anything useful since I lost the data.

I have parent table (`tokens_processed`)

```
CREATE TABLE tokens_processed (
    block_num           INT         PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL REFERENCES lock(block_num) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    done                boolean         DEFAULT FALSE
);
```

2 child tables (`tokop` and `approval`):

```
CREATE TABLE tokop (
    tokop_id            BIGSERIAL       PRIMARY KEY,
    block_num           INT         NOT NULL REFERENCES tokens_processed(block_num) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    ...
)
CREATE TABLE approval (
    approval_id         BIGSERIAL       PRIMARY KEY,
    block_num           INT         NOT NULL REFERENCES tokens_processed(block_num) ON DELETE CASCADE,
   ...
)
```

And a grandchild table :

```
CREATE TABLE tokop_approval (
    tokop_id            BIGINT          NOT NULL REFERENCES tokop(tokop_id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    approval_id         BIGINT          NOT NULL REFERENCES approval(approval_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

The trigger is defined like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tkapr_delete() RETURNS trigger AS  $$

    SELECT contract_id,from_id,to_id,value FROM tokop WHERE tokop_id=OLD.tokop_id  INTO v_contract_id,v_from_id,v_to_id,v_value;
    GET DIAGNOSTICS v_cnt = ROW_COUNT;
    RAISE NOTICE 'contract_id=%, value=% tokop_id=%, v_cnt=%',v_contract_id,v_value,OLD.tokop_id,v_cnt;
    ...
END;

CREATE TRIGGER tkapr_insert AFTER INSERT ON tokop_approval FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tkapr_insert();
CREATE TRIGGER tkapr_delete BEFORE DELETE ON tokop_approval FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE tkapr_delete();
```

When I delete a record from `tokens_processed` , the trigger executed on `tokop_approval` and it shows that the parent record was already deleted. However I need the parent to update some fields in other tables.

Notice output proves this:

```
NOTICE:  contract_id=<NULL>, value=<NULL> tokop_id=131, v_cnt=0
```

How can I execute the trigger BEFORE all the parent records ( parent, and its children) are deleted? Because, right now, when the trigger is executed I am missing required data to continue my process and update some other tables. The reason I have created foreign key constraints (the `REFERENCES`) is to assure Postgres won't call my trigger before parent are deleted, but it does just that :(

Comment: Can't you move the logic that is related to and requires access to `tokop` table to a `BEFORE DELETE` trigger on `tokop` table? If the logic depends on the existence of `tokop_approval` trigger can query for that.

Comment: @RomanKonoval , no I cant. Because the granchild record is linking 2 tables, and when deleted, for me it has a meaning, the meaning that an `unlink` event happened. This event, when fired, must gather info of the parent records, to build a meaningful object, not just the `ID`.

Comment: what I don't understand, is why postgres leaves the database in inconsistent state during DELETE with CASCADE enabled. It first should delete grandchild records, then parent records, and then grandparent record, I think it should follow the hierarchy and start deleting from the bottom. But it does it in reverse order. When you traverse a tree, you have to delete the leaves first, and only after that start deleting intermediate nodes, but Postgres doesn't work this way